# Mensagem 8115, Nível 16, Estado 5- Erro de estouro aritmético ao converter numeric no tipo de dados varchar

Tags: sql

Não consigo encontrar o que há de errado destas conversões :

```
INSERT INTO @RESULTADO
                SELECT @DATA_REF                             as data_ref, 
                       @EMPRESA                              as empresa, 
                       @LOCAL                                as local_loja,
                       Month(@DATA_REF)                      as mes, 
                       Year(@DATA_REF)                       as ano, 
                       Sum(ISNULL(VE.EXTSLDPOS * VE.PRECO1, 0))  as saldo, 
                       Cast(Month(@DATA_REF) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' 
                       + Cast(Year(@DATA_REF) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS ANO_MES,

-- AQUI DAR O ERRO.


DECLARE @RESULTADO TABLE 
  ( 
     data_ref       DATETIME, 
     empresa        INT, 
     mes            INT, 
     ano            INT, 
     saldo          DECIMAL(15, 7), 
     ANO_MES        VARCHAR(7),
     local_loja     INT,
     DESCRICAO      VARCHAR(30) 
  )
```

Comment: aparentemente o erro é auto explicado: converter numerico em varchar

Comment: Mas tipo, eu faço o cast no mês e ano para varchar,e mesmo assim ainda não dar

Comment: pq nao utiliza a formatação de data ao inves de concatenar ?!  qual bd esta usando ?

Comment: Isso é sql Server, certo?

Comment: sim,sqlserver14

Comment: @ArturBruno conseguiu resolver o seu problema?